# If this cell equals 0 then back to blank

Tags: excel

I need help to make the cell blank if it equal 0

I used this in cell

`=SUMIF(Jan!D:D,A4,Jan!E:E)+SUMIF(Feb!D:D,A4,Feb!E:E)+SUMIF(Mar!D:D,A4,Mar!E:E)+SUMIF(Apr!D:D,A4,Apr!E:E)+SUMIF(May!D:D,A4,May!E:E)+SUMIF(Jun!D:D,A4,Jun!E:E)+SUMIF(Jul!D:D,A4,Jul!E:E)+SUMIF(Aug!D:D,A4,Aug!E:E)+SUMIF(Sep!D:D,A4,Sep!E:E)+SUMIF(Oct!D:D,A4,Oct!E:E)+SUMIF(Nov!D:D,A4,Nov!E:E)+SUMIF(Dec!D:D,A4,Dec!E:E)`

Comment: I suggest you'd wrap this in an `IF()` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways I can think of ...

**Method 1 - IF statement** (not ideal given the length of your formula, but it works)

`=IF(SUMIF(Jan!D:D,A4,Jan!E:E)+SUMIF(Feb!D:D,A4,Feb!E:E)+SUMIF(Mar!D:D,A4,Mar!E:E)+SUMIF(Apr!D:D,A4,Apr!E:E)+SUMIF(May!D:D,A4,May!E:E)+SUMIF(Jun!D:D,A4,Jun!E:E)+SUMIF(Jul!D:D,A4,Jul!E:E)+SUMIF(Aug!D:D,A4,Aug!E:E)+SUMIF(Sep!D:D,A4,Sep!E:E)+SUMIF(Oct!D:D,A4,Oct!E:E)+SUMIF(Nov!D:D,A4,Nov!E:E)+SUMIF(Dec!D:D,A4,Dec!E:E) = 0, "", =SUMIF(Jan!D:D,A4,Jan!E:E)+SUMIF(Feb!D:D,A4,Feb!E:E)+SUMIF(Mar!D:D,A4,Mar!E:E)+SUMIF(Apr!D:D,A4,Apr!E:E)+SUMIF(May!D:D,A4,May!E:E)+SUMIF(Jun!D:D,A4,Jun!E:E)+SUMIF(Jul!D:D,A4,Jul!E:E)+SUMIF(Aug!D:D,A4,Aug!E:E)+SUMIF(Sep!D:D,A4,Sep!E:E)+SUMIF(Oct!D:D,A4,Oct!E:E)+SUMIF(Nov!D:D,A4,Nov!E:E)+SUMIF(Dec!D:D,A4,Dec!E:E))`

**Method 2 - Conditional Formatting** (may not suit your requirement)

You can always conditionally format the cell if the value is 0.

[image: CF]

**Method 3 - Worksheet Options** (Could be the best option?!?)

Change the option as shown below in the preferences for the worksheet.

[image: Options]

Comment: Just what I wanted to put :) plus 1 nicely done.

Comment: @SolarMike, great minds ...!  :-)

Comment: @HussainJuma, you need to flag it as the answer then.  That's the point of StackOverflow.  If you get your answer, you flag it.

Comment: There's method 4 - [Custom Number format](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-apply-a-custom-number-format-6c308025-35da-4047-9481-c146a12063df). Same as method 3, but specific to individual cells.  Give number a format of `0;-0;;@` and 0's aren't shown (you may have to change the format of positive and negative numbers to suit).